# NLog, Elmah + shared library

Tags: asp.net-mvc, elmah, nlog

I am trying to come up with a way to create a common library for all my MVC projects. I started off really simple with  BaseController and BaseModel classes. Easy stuff!

Now in my projects I would like to either use Elmah or NLog for logging exceptions and/or tracing info.

Can anyone give me some ideas on the best practices for writing a common library to support both?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use NLog as base for your logging. I've created a small target for NLog which could be used to route exceptions to ELMA. You'll find it at https://github.com/ccellar/nlog-elmah-target.

With this target you are able to use `logger.*Exception( ... )` to log the exception and to pass it to ELMAH.