# Send ELMAH output through NLog

Tags: elmah, nlog

I'm currently using NLog to log security events from my ASP.NET MVC3 application.

Now we have another requirement to add application errors into a separate log.

Since we're already using NLog (and loving the flexibility of the Targets), I would like to configure Elmah to pass errors on to NLog for logging.

Has anyone done this & care to share?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6610735/nlog-elmah-shared-library/6931091#6931091) to a similar question

Comment: @MarnixvanValen that answer explains how to pass errors from NLog to Elmah. Question is about passing Elmah exceptions to NLog.

Answer (score 0):

The same request is written for Log4Net in a [blog](https://www.tigraine.at/2009/11/22/writing-elmah-exceptions-to-log4net)

I have translated it to NLog and updated it to NLog's recommendation:

```csharp
public class NLogErrorLog : XmlFileErrorLog
{
    private static Logger logger = LogManager.GetLogger("elmah");

    public NLogErrorLog(IDictionary config) : base(config)
    {
    }


    public NLogErrorLog(string logPath) : base(logPath)
    {
    }

    public override string Log(Error error)
    {
        //Write whatever you want to NLog
        logger.Error(error.Exception, "Exception logged through ELMAH: " + error.Message);
        return base.Log(error);
    }
}
```

register in web.config

```xml
<elmah>  
    <errorLog type="MyAssembly.NLogErrorLog, MyAssembly" logPath="~/App_Data" />  
</elmah>
```